# Storing a hash using ZINCRBY in redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

I'm attempting to use redis to cache my site search's autocompletion. I came across a tutorial that shows you how to store a plain string as so:

```
$redis.zincrby "search-suggestions:#{prefix.downcase}", 1, term.downcase
```

I was wondering if there was a way to store a hash instead, while still using `ZINCRBY`. I was thinking of attempting to do something like this:

```
$redis.zincrby "search-suggestions:#{prefix.downcase}", 1, {key: val, ...}
```

**Full Code Example:**

```
class SearchSuggestion
  def self.terms_for(prefix)
    $redis.zrevrange "search-suggestions:#{prefix.downcase}", 0, 9
  end 

  def self.index_products
    Product.find_each do |product|
      index_term(product.name)
      product.name.split.each { |t| index_term(t) }
      index_term(product.category)
    end
  end

  def self.index_term(term)
    1.upto(term.length - 1) do |n|
      prefix = term[0, n]
      $redis.zincrby "search-suggestions:#{prefix.downcase}", 1, term.downcase
    end
  end
end
```

Source: [Railscast: Episode #399](http://railscasts.com/episodes/399-autocomplete-search-terms?view=asciicast)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`zincrby`](https://redis.io/commands/zincrby) works with the sorted set of strings, but nothing prevents you from using a JSON representation of your object:

[image: interactive redis example]

```
$redis.zincrby "search-suggestions:#{prefix.downcase}",
               1,
               JSON.dump({key: val, ...})
```